# Dialog.dimiss() not working

Tags: java, android, button, mobile, dialog

So I have a dialog that opens that should close when the exit button is clicked. It seems to close quickly and then comes back again. It is as if a second dialog is opened once I dismiss the first one. Anyone have any ideas?
(Edited to include more code)

This is my dialog code:

```
    buildMoreButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buildMore);
    buildMoreButton.setText("BUILD");
    buildMoreButton.setBackgroundColor(-65536);
    buildMoreButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                buildMoreButton.setBackgroundColor(-1);
            }//end if
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                buildMoreButton.setBackgroundColor(-65536);
            }//end else if

            //open dialog for building choices
            buildingSelect = new Dialog(runGraphics.this);
            buildingSelect.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            buildingSelect.setTitle("Building Selection");

            exit = (Button) buildingSelect.findViewById(R.id.exit);
            exit.setText("X");
            exit.setBackgroundColor(-65536);
            exit.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    {
                        exit.setBackgroundColor(-1);
                    }//end if
                    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    {
                        exit.setBackgroundColor(-65536);
                        buildingSelect.dismiss();
                    }//end else if

                    return false;
                }//end onTouch          
            });//end OnTouchListener

            colonyHut = (ImageView) buildingSelect.findViewById(R.id.colonyHut);

            buildingSelect.show();
            return false;
        }//end onTouch function

    });//end OnTouchListener
```

Any help is appreciated.
Not positive exactly why it seems that a second dialog is popping up when the dismiss is called.

Comment: when you want to close the Dialog when the button is touched or after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dismiss the Dialog when it detects the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` not after and before you clicked because you are calling `dismiss` twice.

**solution:**

```
  buildMoreButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buildMore);
    buildMoreButton.setText("BUILD");
    buildMoreButton.setBackgroundColor(-65536);
    buildMoreButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                buildMoreButton.setBackgroundColor(-1);
            }//end if
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                buildMoreButton.setBackgroundColor(-65536);
            }//end else if



    });//end OnTouchListener

//open dialog for building choices
            buildingSelect = new Dialog(runGraphics.this);
            buildingSelect.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            buildingSelect.setTitle("Building Selection");

            exit = (Button) buildingSelect.findViewById(R.id.exit);
            exit.setText("X");
            exit.setBackgroundColor(-65536);
            exit.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    {
                        exit.setBackgroundColor(-1);
                    }//end if
                    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    {
                        exit.setBackgroundColor(-65536);
                        buildingSelect.dismiss();
                    }//end else if

                    return false;
                }//end onTouch          
            });//end OnTouchListener

            colonyHut = (ImageView) buildingSelect.findViewById(R.id.colonyHut);

            buildingSelect.show();
            return false;
    }//end onTouch function
```

Comment: I changed it as you said and I still end up with the same issue. The box seems to start to disappear and then comes back. Then the exit button is no longer clickable.

Comment: @saboehnke can post your whole code.. because I think you re calling it again

Comment: @saboehnke i see the problem you are recreating the dialog each time you click. edditted.

Comment: @saboehnke put it outside your ontouch.

Comment: I can't do it that way. The point of this is the dialog should display when the BUILD button is pressed. Your example does not allow it to be created again.

Comment: @saboehnke put it onclick not in ontouch of the buildMoreButton

Comment: I need to change the onTouch of buildMoreButton to onClick instead? That doesn't give me the same options when it comes to motionevents

Comment: @saboehnke why use ontouch??

Comment: Because it gives me the options of motionevents?

Comment: @saboehnke you mean changing the background when the button is touch, cause you can do that with selector xml

Comment: You're just confusing me now. The dialog opens when the BUILD button is pressed. The dialog should then close when the exit button is pressed. The way I have it set up works except that it for some reason comes up with another dialog after the first one closes.

Comment: @saboehnke As I keep saying that is because of the Ontouch.. that you should use onClick instead.

Comment: Ok I will give it a shot. Thank you. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: That worked. I just had to get rid of some of the stuff I was using also. But could you explain why onClick would work and onTouch wouldn't? Just for future use? And thank you very much. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @saboehnke that is because when you dismiss the buildingSelect behind the scene the buildMoreButton actually got touch.